# Sqoop action erroring in oozie workflow

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, oozie

i am facing below error from sqoop action in oozie... can any one pls help

> 1703 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool  - Got error
>   creating database manager: java.io.IOException: No manager for connect
>   string: jdbc:teradata://tdproda/DATABASE=INOVBIDT,LOGMECH=LDAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to install and configure a Teradata connector for Sqoop.

See here:
http://www.cloudera.com/content/support/en/downloads/download-components/download-products/downloads-listing/connectors/teradata.html

Comment: hi thanks for your reply.. 

the same query is working from command line, but when i run the sqoop job thru oozie, its failing. I hope all the connectors were present, hence my query is working from command line. 

Pls guide...

Comment: Oozie needs the JDBC drivers in the sharelib location in HDFS (or anywhere in HDFS and use oozie.libpath= in job.properties to point to the right location.

Comment: thank you for the reply @Gwen Shapira. Yes you are correct the supporting jar files (teradata connectors + jdbc support jar files --> terajdbc4.jar, tdgssconfig.jar ), should be available in "lib" folder of our workflow deployment path.

Comment: Also, we need to add the below config. info into our sqoop action in oozie

<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>sqoop.connection.factories</name>
    <value>com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.TeradataManagerFactory</value>
  </property>
</configuration>